# Node MYSQL exports returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot that has integration with mysql. To make it easier, I created a central file for the mysql database (configs/mysql.js) and, when the command needs it, it will send the query request to that file and finally, it will return the processed value. But when I try to do this, the return is undefined in the console (of the command), but in the mysql.js console, it shows the correct value.

MYSQL.js Code

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: config.URL,
  user: config.dbUser,
  password: config.dbPassword,
  database: config.database
});
  connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("[MYSQL] Error on Connection: " + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log("[MYSQL] Connected with ID " + connection.threadId + "!");
});

function query(sql) {
  connection.query(sql, function(error, result, fields) {
    if (error) return error;
    const analise = JSON.stringify(result[0]);
    console.log(analise) //it's return the value correct
    return analise
  });
}

exports.connection = connection;
exports.query = query;
```

The Request

```js
const status1 = await mysql.query("SELECT `status` FROM `server_status`");
  console.log(status1); //it's return undefined
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for `mysql` you can`t use `return` in callback function.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.URL,
    user: config.dbUser,
    password: config.dbPassword,
    database: config.database,
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('[MYSQL] Error on Connection: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log('[MYSQL] Connected with ID ' + connection.threadId + '!');
});

function query(sql) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        connection.query(sql, function(error, result, fields) {
            if (error) return error;
            const analise = JSON.stringify(result[0]);
            console.log(analise); //it's return the value correct
            resolve(analise);
        });
    });
}

exports.connection = connection;
exports.query = query;
```

```js
const status1 = await mysql.query("SELECT `status` FROM `server_status`");
```